# Access importing wrong columns

Tags: ms-access, csv

Help! Access is importing wrong columns from a csv file.  There are no commas in the csv and there should not be any spaces like (space)(space), but just (space).  I'm ending up with '' in the SERIAL_NR header, but in the actual csv there are values.

[image]

This is giving me 1000 extra rows.  Is there anything else to check for?

Comment: It looks like other fields are messed up as well - addresses are in the "model" column, staes & cities are in the "zip code" column, etc.  Can you include a few lines of the .csv input file, including headings (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

It's sneaky and underhanded, but the alt+enter character [chr(10)] was included in a few of the cells. I used the following vba code to get rid of it.

```
sub cleaner()
Dim enterchar as string

enterchar = chr(10)

activesheet.usedrange.Replace What:=enterchar, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _ 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False 

end sub
```

Pretty nifty for prepping a csv for import into Access.  I've created an add-in for cleaning csv's (eliminating duplicates, special char's, etc.) if anyone's interested I'll post.

Thanks all!